# Laravel. php artisan display return [];

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

When I use php artisan command, it display "return [];" 
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsV6N.png)
Above the header of my web page there is "return []"; too. Does anyone know what this is caused by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Laravel configuration file is a PHP file that contains an array, when your application is initialised Laravel loads each configuration file (`config/*.php`) and adds the array to your configuration.

The problem you're experiencing appears to be due to the fact that your application has a configuration file that is being loaded not as PHP but instead as a text file. This can be caused by a config file missing the opening `<?php`, which is required for the file to be treated as PHP. For example, if you create a file in `config` called `example.php` with the following contents:

```
return [

];
```

You would see the behaviour you're experiencing in the screenshot. Therefore you should visit your `config` directory and identify any file that is missing the opening `<?php`.